# Two-dimensional optimization: need an appropriate measure of confidence

Tags: optimization

I have a fitness function $f(x,y)$, which I am sampling at discrete $x$ and $y$ in order to  minimize $f$. In addition to the location of the minimum, I would like to give an appropriate measure of confidence or quality of the determined location, so that I can detect if the minimum is rather wide, or if $f$ is non-convex.

Without making further assumptions about $f$, what would be an appropriate measure of quality?

Comment: What method are you using to find the minimum? Or are you just sampling the function at many points and finding the minimum of this list?

Comment: Indeed I'm sampling the function.

Comment: I should add I'm sampling the function in a rectangular grid of $(x,y)$ values.

Comment: Without further assumptions about $f$, you can say very little. It might be a rapidly oscillating function that you have undersampled, like $\sin(100x)$.

Comment: Okay, what if we exclude undersampling and assume that the function is steady?